# Is it possible to automatically generate multiple Vimeo access tokens for a single user?

Tags: oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm working on a project were I need to be able to have multiple App users upload videos under a single Vimeo account. I would like to do this in a secure way, so I would like to automatically generate the access tokens on the App's API server, and pass *this* off to the front-end, so that if a user should no longer have access to the system, their access token can be revoked (or even better, expire). I know that I can generate more than one token through a typical user log-in challenge screen, but I really want to automate this process, handling the authentication server-side, and passing along access tokens of the appropriate type to each user based on their user class.

Is it possible to generate these tokens without having to go through the challenge screen and redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the right workflow to use, but unfortunately Vimeo does not offer any of those features yet.

In the future they will support duplicating tokens and expirations so that you can send your user through one redirect flow for multiple tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. This is what my research turned up, but I wanted to be sure that I hadn't missed anything.